# Calling function from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React v0.14.8. I tried to call the `fetchData` function from another component. Here is my code:

```
export default class TagUtils extends React.Component {
    deleteTag = () => {
        Tags.deleteTag(this.props.tag).then(function(response){
           if(response.message === 'tag successfully deleted')
                Sidebar.fetchData(); 
        });
    }
// other codes
```

And:

```
export default class Sidebar extends React.Component {
fetchData() {
        Tags.getTags().done((response) => {
            this.setState({tags: response.tags || [], loaded: true});
        });
    }
//other codes
```

When I called `deleteTag`, I got this error in my console:

```
TypeError: _SidebarJsx2.default.fetchData is not a function
```

Comment: how do you pass `fetchData` to child component? could you post more code

Comment: I just import the Sidebar component using es6 import syntax

Comment: you should not call methods from other component in such way, you should pass method through props

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call `Sidebar.fetchData` because `fetchData` is not a *static* member of `Sidebar`, it is an *instance* member. This means you need an instance of `Sidebar` to call `fetchData` on, for example `new Sidebar().fetchData()`. Of course, this is not how a React component is supposed to be used, and it would *not* set state on all other `Sidebar` instances, so it wouldn't be meaningful.

What you want to do is pass a callback to your `TagUtils` component:

```
export default class TagUtils extends React.Component {
    deleteTag = () => {
        Tags.deleteTag(this.props.tag).then((response) => {
           if(response.message === 'tag successfully deleted')
                this.props.onDeleteTag(); 
        });
    }
}

export default class Sidebar extends React.Component {
    fetchData() {
        Tags.getTags().done((response) => {
            this.setState({tags: response.tags || [], loaded: true});
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            { this.state.tags.map((tag) => 
                   <TagUtils tag={tag} onDeleteTag={this.fetchData} />) }
        );
    }
}
```

If you have to thread this callback through several layers of components that's okay, that's typical in React. However, if you find yourself passing a lot of stuff down props through many component layers that seem out of place, or trying to reconcile changes across large horizontal spaces in your app, this is a primary use-case for things like [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/) and [Redux](http://redux.js.org/).